# Inverse function as composition and as solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to reconcile in my mind two definitions that are separate there as of now:

My first definition of inverse of an onto function: $g$ is the inverse of $f$ iff $g(f(x))=x$.

It is very intuitive as the one that undoes the operation of the original function.

But often, when we want to actually find an expression for the inverse we use the resource of "solving for x", and to me it seems miraculous that it produces the inverse function in the sense of the composition definition.

**So:** What is the explanation for that "miracle"?

P.S. I've read https://blogs.ams.org/matheducation/2016/11/28/inverse-functions-were-teaching-it-all-wrong/ and it helped a little, but it seems aimed at the ones who already understand the concept, not to the student.

Comment: This is not clear.  What miracle?  Sometimes we can solve for an explicit inverse function in closed form and sometimes we can't.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Should say:  I looked over the blog post and I can't sort out what point the writer is making, if any.  True, one should not confuse the existence of an inverse function with a simple closed form presentation of it.  That poses real computational problems, though not much of an abstract problem really.  Beyond that, what is there to say?

Comment: Sorry! No, no, the intent of my question is like why is that if I start with say y=2x+30 and solve for x, then exchange the letters, we obtain a function that satisfy the definition of being the inverse with respect to composition. To me, those things aren't related, it seems like a miracle. Sorry, English is not my native language, but I hope it's better now!

Comment: But...say we are given that $y=2x+30$ and we are given the value of $y$ and that we seek $x$ which makes the equation true.  That means solving for $x$ in that equation.  Literally.  The uncertain part is whether, in a general setting, there will always be a unique solution.  Sometimes there are no solutions, sometimes there are more than one.

Comment: I think the sleight-of-hand switch of variables might cause confusion.  Given $y=2x+30$  we solve for $x=g(y)$.  Then we say something like "well, variable names are arbitrary anyway, so lets just speak of a function $g(x)$ and, as usual, we can have $g(x)=y$".  That can definitely lead to confusion.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to do it explicitly:  take $f(x)=2x+30$.  We seek a function $g(x)$ such that $f\circ g(x)=x$.   Thus we want $x=f(g(x))=2g(x)+30$ which implies $g(x)=\frac {x-30}2$.  Note that this is precisely the same as "solving for $x$ given $y=2x-30$".

Comment: @lulu this shows how to get a right inverse, but the user asks for a left inverse

Comment: @Sambo Left and right inverses are the same. If  $g$ is a right inverse as in my computation and $h$ is the desired left inverse, then, letting $id(x)$ denote the identity function, $h=h\circ id=h\circ (f\circ g)=(h\circ f)\circ g=id\circ g=g$.  Beauty of associative operations.  Is this the point that is causing confusion?

Comment: Here's another way to see that a right inverse must also be a left inverse.  Keep in mind that $f$ really must be $1:1$ here, meaning that $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$.  If it isn't, the left inverse can't be defined.  But then $f(g(x))=x\implies f(g(f(x))=f(x)$ so we must have $g(f(x))=x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I got it! The explicit example was the one that helped the most! ^^